# Hackerrank Compare the Triplets Javascript

Tags: javascript, integer

I'm aware that there is already a thread on this topic, however I'm just wondering why this solution isn't working for HackerRank's "Compare the Triplets" problem?  I'm only getting an output of 1 when it should be 1 1.

The problem states that if a0 > b0, a1 > b1, or a2 > b2 (and vice versa), the result should print separate spaced integers of 1 for any comparison that is not equal.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem

```js
function solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {
    
    var solution = []

    if (a0 > b0 || a1 > b1 || a2 > b2) {
        solution += 1;
    } else if (a0 < b0 || a1 < b1 || a2 < b2 ) {
        solution += 1;
    }
    return solution.split('');
}
```

---- UPDATE ----

The code above only worked for the first test case and not the rest.  The code below, although clunky, worked for all test cases.

```js
function solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {
    var s = [0, 0];
    
    if (a0 > b0) {s[0] += 1;} 
    if (a1 > b1) {s[0] += 1;} 
    if (a2 > b2) {s[0] += 1;}
    if (a0 < b0) {s[1] += 1;}
    if (a1 < b1) {s[1] += 1;}
    if (a2 < b2) {s[1] += 1;}
        
    return s;
}
```

---

Ghost of Christmas Future Update (11/8/23)

I keep getting notifications about this post so I thought I'd go back and solve it again as an employed software engineer.  Asking questions on S/O was scary when I first started because I had no idea what I was doing.  Fast forward nearly six years and I still feel like I have no idea what I'm doing half of the time, but now I code for a living and love it.  Here's how I'd solve it now.

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    let aliceTotal = 0;
    let bobTotal = 0;
    
    a.map((aliceScore, i) => {
        aliceScore > b[i] ? alice += 1 : 
        aliceScore < b[i] ? bob += 1 : 
        0;
    });
    
    return [aliceTotal, bobTotal];
}
```

Comment: An output to what input? So far you’ve only shown a function declaration. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you allowed to let others help on code challgenges?

Comment: To add values to an array use `solution.push(1)`, not `solution += 1`.

Comment: `solution.split('')` you cant split an array?!

Comment: @JonasW. This doesn't look like a open competition so it should be fine.

Comment: @Xufox Apologies - I'm new to this, that's why I included the link.  I'll update now.

Comment: @JonasW. this solution was accepted as correct once I removed "else" from the solution above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many different solutions to this problem, but the issue with the mentioned solution is that there should not be "else" statement because in that case the second comparison never happens. Corrected:

```
function solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {

    var solution = []

    if (a0 > b0 || a1 > b1 || a2 > b2) {
        solution += 1;
    }
if (a0 < b0 || a1 < b1 || a2 < b2 ) {
        solution += 1;
    }
    return solution.split('');
}
```

Comment: Hell yeah, that was it.  Thanks @Khyati.  I'm curious though, would this solution be considered a good practice?  I was surprised that I didn't find any similar solutions online, most were pretty long and verbose.

Comment: Hi Justin, this solution cannot be considered a good one because it will only give correct result if the score for both are either 0 or 1. But for the case when score of any 1 will be 2/3, this solution will not yield correct result.
eg: if the input set become-
5, 6, 7,
3, 8, 10

Following can be a solution:
function solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {

    score_a = ((a0>b0)?1:0)+ ((a1>b1)?1:0)+ ((a2>b2)?1:0) ;
    score_b = ((a0<b0)?1:0)+ ((a1<b1)?1:0)+ ((a2<b2)?1:0) ;
    return [score_a, score_b];
}

Comment: Thanks @Khyati.  I tried it again after the last message and found that it didn't work for the rest of the test cases, so I ended up just using a bunch of if statements.  I'm still familiarizing myself with operators like : and ? which seem to be much more efficient.

Comment: Did U check this condition var a = [17,28,30] and var b = [99,16,8] above solution is wrong;

Answer (score 12):

seems to pass in hackerrank if a and b treated as arrays:

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    let score = [0,0]

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] > b[i] ? score[0]++ : a[i] < b[i] ? score[1]++ : ""
    return score
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution, which I think is much simpler and does not assume the length of the rating params.

```
let counterA = 0,
    counterB = 0;
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(a[i] > b[i]){
        counterA++;
    }
    else if(a[i] < b[i]){
        counterB++;
    }
}

return [counterA,counterB];
```

Answer (score 4):

my solution. I think it's quite readable.

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {

let aScore = 0;
let bScore = 0;

a.forEach((x,index)=>{
    if (x>b[index]) {
        aScore++;
    } else if (x<b[index]) {
        bScore++;
    }
});

return [aScore, bScore];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

More compact and better answer in ES6 Syntax for this question can be:

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {

    let ascore = 0, bscore = 0;
    a.forEach((item, i) => {
        (a[i] > b[i]) && ascore++;
        (a[i] < b[i]) && bscore++;
    });

    return [ascore, bscore];
}
```

or you can refer this:

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {

    let score = [0, 0];
    a.forEach((item, i) => {
        (a[i] > b[i]) && score[0]++;
        (a[i] < b[i]) && score[1]++;
    });

    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of Javascript type coercion, some of the answers here have unnecessary conditionals and ternary operators.

In the 2019 iteration of the Hackerrank triplet problem they ask that your final output is an array with the score of alice first, then bob, i.e, `[2,1]`

so you can just do:

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
  var alice = (a[0] > b[0]) + (a[1] > b[1]) + (a[2] > b[2]);
  var bob = (a[0] < b[0]) + (a[1] < b[1]) + (a[2] < b[2]);
  return [alice, bob];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small hint:

```
  console.log((a0 > b0) + (a1 > b1) + (a2 > b2))) // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [9, 7, 3];
var b = [3, 2, 1];

function compareTriplets(a, b){
    var score = [0, 0];
    for(var i = 0; i <= a.length; i +=1){
        if(a[i] > b[i]){
            score[0]+=1;
        } else if(a[i] < b[i]){
            score[1]+=1;
        } else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Solution
**First Way**

```
function compare(a, b) {
  const score = [0, 0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) {
      score[0]++;
    } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
      score[1]++;
    } else {
      score[1] === score[1];
    }
  }
}
```

**Second Way**

```
function compare(a, b) {
  const score = [0, 0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a[i] > b[i] ? score[0]++ : a[i] < b[i] ? score[1]++ : score[1] === score[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain what your answer does

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with the most absurdly unreadable but concise way of doing this:

```
const compareTriplets = (a, b) => [[a, b], [b, a]].map((c, i) => c[0].reduce((acc, _curr, i) => acc + (c[0][i] > c[1][i]), 0));
```

I'm positive I could extend this to handle a hypothetically (within the limits of the language) infinite amount of tuples as well, but I'm done for the day.

Comment: i would leave any company that had this in their codebase

Comment: I wouldn't blame you haha. I would kill anyone who tried to get something like this through code review

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary operator

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

ReactJS uses a lot of ternary operator for conditional rendering. Pretty neat and would be a useful shortcut in the future :P

```js
 function compareTriplets(a, b) {
  
   let result = [0,0];

   a.forEach((element, i) =>  
        a[i] > b[i] ? result[0]++ : 
        a[i] < b[i] ? result[1]++ : 
        null )

   return result 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this one** I use looping with map and it's work:

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
 let nilaiA =0, nilaiB=0;
 a.map((item, i) => {
     if(item > b[i]){
         nilaiA++
     }else if(item < b[i]){
         nilaiB++
     }
 })

 return [nilaiA,nilaiB] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a point each time an element of the first tuple is greater than the one in the second, i.e

```
let solution = [0,0];
a0>b0?solution[0]+=1:a0<b0?solution[1]+=1:'';
```

then return the solution array not splitted

Answer (score 0):

Going off of your update I was able to enhance it further since the input they are giving you is already two arrays it was cleaner to do it this way. The method that you gave was throwing runtime errors.

```
function solve(a, b) {

    var results = [0,0];

    if (a[0] > b[0]) {results[0] += 1;} 
    if (a[1] > b[1]) {results[0] += 1;} 
    if (a[2] > b[2]) {results[0] += 1;}
    if (a[0] < b[0]) {results[1] += 1;}
    if (a[1] < b[1]) {results[1] += 1;}
    if (a[2] < b[2]) {results[1] += 1;}

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this by the below solution.

```
    function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    let alice = 0, bob = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if (a[i] > b[i]) alice += 1;
        if(a[i]<b[i]) bob +=1
    }
    return [alice,bob]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    var score = [0, 0];

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {       // iterate through the array
    if (a[i] > b[i]) {
        result[0]++;
    } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
        result[1]++;
    }
}
return score;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

an even simpler way using a scoreboard and incrementing

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
let scoreBoard = [0, 0]
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) {
        scoreBoard[0]++
    } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
        scoreBoard[1]++
    }
}
return scoreBoard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    // let a =[17,28,30]
    // let b=[99,16,8]
    let a1 = 0,b1=0;
    for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        
            if(a[i]> b[i]) {
                a1++
            }
            else if(a[i]<b[i]){
                    b1++
                }
            
           
        }
        return [a1,b1];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution you can try...

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
let p1 = 0, p2 = 0, aliceScore = 0, bobScore = 0;
while (p1 < a.length && p2 < b.length) {
    if (a[p1] > b[p2]) {
        aliceScore += 1;
        p1 += 1;
        p2 += 1;
    } else if (a[p1] < b[p2]) {
        bobScore += 1;
        p1 += 1;
        p2 += 1;

    } else {
        p1 += 1;
        p2 += 1;
    }
}
return [aliceScore, bobScore];
}
compareTriplets([10 ,12, 50],[20,20,10]);
```

[Click here to RUN](https://repl.it/@jaymanale/compareTripletsjs)